# HttpContext vs. HttpListenerContext AcceptWebSocketRequest unable to cast overridden async func

Tags: c#, .net, casting, async-await

I'm trying to use `HttpContextBase` to share code between an `HttpListener` and an `HttpHandler`. `HttpContextWrapper` is provided already but I have to make my own `HttpListenerContextWrapper`, which is easy enough until I get to `AcceptWebSocketRequest`. The problem is that the callback in `HttpContextBase.AcceptWebSocketRequest` is typed `Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task>` instead of `Func<WebSocketContext, Task>` and I am struggling to convert it in my derived class.

```
public class HttpListenerContextWrapper : HttpContextBase
{
    private HttpListenerContext _context;

    public HttpListenerContextWrapper(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override async void AcceptWebSocketRequest(Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task> callback)
    {
        // can't implicitly convert HttpListenerWebSocketContext to AspNetWebSocketContext..
        await callback(await _context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null));

        // throws at runtime..
        await callback((AspNetWebSocketContext)(WebSocketContext)await _context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null));

        // throws at runtime..
        await ((Func<WebSocketContext, Task>)callback)(await _context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null));

        // throws at runtime..
        await ((Func<HttpListenerWebSocketContext, Task>)callback)(await _context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null))
    }

    // no suitable method found to override..
    public override async void AcceptWebSocketRequest(Func<WebSocketContext, Task> callback)
    {
```

The runtime exception is always: `Unable to cast object of type Func<AspNetWebSocketContext,Task> to type Func<WebSocketContext,Task>
..at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__4`

The code that calls `AcceptWebSocketRequest` is typed `WebSocketContext` and it works well when using `HttpContext` or `HttpListenerContext` directly. Is there a way to create a compatible callback? Or is there a better way to abstract `HttpContext` and `HttpListenerContext`?

If I copy the code for `HttpContextBase` and change the type to `WebSocketContext` everything works, but I'd rather not have to keep a butchered up copy of `HttpContextBase` and `HttpContextWrapper` in my project.

**edit:** here's the code where the method is being used.

```
private async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContextBase context)
{
    if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
        await context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(HandleWebsocketRequest);
...

private async Task HandleWebsocketRequest(WebSocketContext context)
{
    ...
```

Comment: Just to make sure. `AcceptWebSocketAsync` returns `HttpListenerWebSocketContext` and you want to cast it to `AspNetWebSocketContext`? Because that can never happen as `HttpListenerWebSocketContext` doesn't inherit from `AspNetWebSocketContext`

Comment: I want to cast both the HttpListenerWebSocketContext returned from AcceptWebSocketAsync and the callback parameter to WebSocketContext which is the common base for AspNetWebSocketContext and HttpListenerWebSocketContext. The callback parameter is being implicitly cast from WebSocketContext to AspNetWebSocketContext already, I need a way to prevent that or convert it back.

Comment: `callback` is a delegate that accepts `AspNetWebSocketContext`. You can't make it accept `WebSocketContext` as the method expects `AspNetWebSocketContext`.

Comment: The callback *does* accept WebSocketContext though. That is what I pass to the HttpContextWrapper implementation and it works fine.

Comment: The callback in your code `Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task> callback` accepts `AspNetWebSocketContext`.

Comment: HttpContextWrapper also takes `Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task>` and I am passing `Func<WebSocketContext, Task>` and it works. Func params are contravariant in C#, so this is allowed, and it compiles and functions properly for HttpContextWrapper but in my derived class it throws at runtime.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you pass to the `callback` parameter. It matters what type the parameter is. Of course you can pass a delegate that accepts a base class of `AspNetWebSocketContext`. The point (in my first comment) is that `HttpListenerWebSocketContext ` isn't a base class of `AspNetWebSocketContext`

Comment: The callback is `Func<WebSocketContext, Task>` it accepts AspNetWebSocketContext as well as HttpListenerWebSocketContext. But when the callback is first cast to `Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task>` for this override then it throws at runtime. There does not exist an actual callback typed `Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task>` in my project. What's strange, if you look at the runtime exception, it's complaining about casting it back to its actual type.

Comment: No. The callback (in your code) is `Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task>` You can pass a delegate that accepts `WebSocketContext` as it's a base class of `AspNetWebSocketContext` but not `HttpListenerWebSocketContext`

Comment: I will edit the question and include the code for the actual callback that is passed. WebSocketContext is also the base class of HttpListenerWebSocketContext btw.

Comment: That doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass `Func<WebSocketContext, Task>` into the `Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task>` parameter and then cast it back to `Func<WebSocketContext, Task>` so you can pass in `HttpListenerWebSocketContext` you need to specifically state that type when you create the delegate.

If you let the compiler infer that it will create a `Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task>` delegate that can't accept `HttpListenerWebSocketContext`.

So instead of:

```
await context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(HandleWebsocketRequest);
```

You need:

```
Func<WebSocketContext, Task> action = HandleWebsocketRequest;
await context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(action);
```

And in `AcceptWebSocketRequest` you need to cast it back:

```
await ((Func<WebSocketContext, Task>)callback)(await _context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null));
```

However, that's **extremely dangerous and bad design** as the `callback` parameter is of type `Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task>` and you can't guarantee all callers will send a `Func<WebSocketContext, Task>` and not a `Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task>` as an argument.

Comment: That worked thanks! I still don't understand why it's necessary to cast `HandleWebsocketRequest` to `(Func<WebSocketContext, Task>)HandleWebsocketRequest` when that is its definition already? Regarding the danger, I will just have HttpListenerContextWrapper throw if it's fed an AspNetWebSocketContext - it shouldn't happen since that is what HttpContextWrapper is for.

Comment: @gordy The method's signature doesn't matter. The relevant definition is of the variable (or parameter) you are setting which in your case is `Func<AspNetWebSocketContext, Task>`. If the signature determined the delegate's type you could simply do `var action = HandleWebsocketRequest` (which of course you can't. You don't need to throw an exception. The runtime will throw one for you, as you've encountered.